# How to fix 'no item called "package:pkg" on the search list' without using library(pkg)?

Tags: r, debugging

I am writing a package named testpkg and have put quantmod in the Depends section of the DESCRIPTION file.

I have written the following functions:

```
#' hello1
#'
#' @return NA
#' @export
hello1 <- function() {
  print("hello1!")
  quantmod::is.HLC("Hello, world!")
}

#' hello2
#'
#' @return NA
#' @export
hello2 <- function () {

    x <- structure(c(25.85, 25.639999, 26.700001, 26.26, 26.92, 27.870001,
                   25.26, 25.52, 26.66, 25.610001, 26.85, 27.74, 26352700, 32512200,
                   64264600, 25.610001, 26.85, 27.74),
                 .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC",
                 src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1437653990.9303, class = c("POSIXct",
                                                                               "POSIXt")),
                 class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1167782400,
                                                              1167868800, 1167955200),
                                                            tzone = "UTC",
                                                            tclass = "Date"),
                 .Dim = c(3L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("YHOO.Open", "YHOO.High", "YHOO.Low",
                                                            "YHOO.Close", "YHOO.Volume", "YHOO.Adjusted")))
    print(x)
    quantmod::chartSeries(x)

}
```

Now, when I go into a project and run `testpkg::hello1()`, I get the output I expected.

However, if I run `testpkg::hello2()`, I can see that `x` is printed but the plot is not generated. I get the error:

```
Error in as.environment("package:quantmod") : 
  no item called "package:quantmod" on the search list
```

I know I can fix this by calling `library(quantmod)` before making the call to `testpkg::hello2()` but it seems odd to me that `testpkg::hello1()` can run error-free without calling `library(quantmod)`. What is the reason for this and is there an alternative way to run `testpkg::hello2()` without calling `library(quantmod)` first?

Comment: My guess is that this is because quantmod is in Depends instead of Imports and you haven't called `library(testpkg)`, which would load and attach quantmod.

Comment: Your suggestion does fix the error (actually, not moving maintaining quantmod in Depends also works). However, I'd to avoid the call to library(quantmod) because I plan to use this function in another package and according to [Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html): "Never use library() in a package". Also, isn't it weird that `testpkg::hello1()` works without calling to `library(quantmod)` first despite both are using functions from `quantmod`?

Comment: I said you need to call `library(testpkg)`; I did not say you need to call `library(quantmod)`.  If you intend to use `testpkg` code in another package, then you need to ensure the other package Depends on `testpkg`.  The error is because `chartSeries` calls `chartTheme`, which expects quantmod to be loaded and attached.  That also means you need to leave quantmod in Depends.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Would you like to change your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?